# Compound mysql query anomality issues

Tags: mysql

Suppose one has the following three tables:

- #### `td_idea`

  ```
  +----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
  | idea_id  |  idea_name   |  idea_submitter_id   |   idea_status    |
  +----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
  | 1        |  shirt       |           3          |   Design         |
  | 2        |  top         |           1          |   Color          |
  +----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+
  ```
- #### `td_idea_contribution`

  ```
  +------------------+------------+-----------------+
  | contribution_id  |  idea_id   |  submitter_id   |
  +------------------+------------+-----------------+
  |        1         |      1     |        3        |
  |        2         |      1     |        4        |
  |        3         |      1     |        7        |
  |        4         |      1     |        10       |
  |        5         |      2     |        3        |
  |        6         |      2     |        10       |
  +------------------+------------+-----------------+
  ```

  This table shows the contribution that users have made on a particular idea.
- #### `td_idea_contribution_like`

  ```
  +----------+--------------------+-----------------+
  | like_id  |  contribution_id   |  submitter_id   |
  +----------+--------------------+-----------------+
  |     1    |          1         |        1        |
  |     2    |          1         |        4        |
  |     3    |          2         |        24       |
  |     4    |          1         |        73       |
  |     5    |          4         |        124      |
  |     6    |          2         |        34       |
  |     7    |          1         |        75       |
  |     8    |          3         |        124      |
  +----------+--------------------+-----------------+
  ```

I want to display all the contributions for a particular `idea_id`, each showing the number of votes for each contribution listed.

So, for `idea_id = 1`, I wish to see the following output:

```
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
|  contribution_id |    total_likes   |    user_id   |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
|        1         |        4         |      3       |
|        2         |        2         |      4       |
|        3         |        1         |      7       |
|        4         |        1         |     10       |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

I am currently using the following query, but weird results are being displayed:

```
SELECT   td_idea.idea_id,
         td_idea_contribution.contributuion_id,
         td_idea_contribution.submitter_id,
         COUNT(td_idea_contribution_like.contribution_like_id) AS tot_like
FROM     td_idea, td_idea_contribution, td_idea_contribution_like
WHERE    td_idea.idea_id = td_idea_contribution.idea_id 
     AND td_idea_contribution.contribution_id = td_idea_contribution_like.contribution_id
     AND td_idea.idea_id = '$id'
     AND td_idea.status LIKE '%Design%'
ORDER BY tot_like DESC
```

---

**EDIT**

I am not getting an error, I am just getting an anomalous result containing one single record as follows:

```
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
|  contribution_id |    total_likes   |    user_id   |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
|        1         |        8         |      3       |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Looking at the error and the query you posted, one immediately sees that they aren't the same.

Comment: The query you posted has four columns in the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`GROUP BY` (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html):

> If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.

This is what is happening in your case.  To prevent it, you need to *group* your results by `contribution_id`:

```
SELECT   contribution_id,
         COUNT(*) AS total_likes,
         c.submitter_id AS user_id
FROM     td_idea                   i
    JOIN td_idea_contribution      c USING (        idea_id)
    JOIN td_idea_contribution_like l USING (contribution_id)
WHERE    idea_id = 1
     AND idea_status LIKE '%Design%'
GROUP BY contribution_id
ORDER BY total_likes DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69422b/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

The query seems to lack a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT
    i.idea_id,
    i_c.contribution_id,
    i_c.submitter_id,
    COUNT(i_c_l.contribution_like_id) AS tot_like 

FROM td_idea AS i
JOIN td_idea_contribution AS i_c USING ( idea_id )
JOIN td_idea_contribution_like AS i_c_l USING ( contribution_id )

WHERE
    i.idea_id='$id'
    AND i.status LIKE '%Design%'

GROUP BY idea_id, contribution_id
ORDER BY tot_like DESC
```

P.S.: Avoid using the obsolete, obscure form `FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.pk = t2.fk`. Prefer the more explicit `FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.pk = t2.fk)`

P.S. 2: If the Idea you are looking at happens to have no "likes" or no "contribution", then the query returns nothing. Replace all `JOIN` clauses by `LEFT JOIN` to retrieve such Ideas anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT idea.idea_id,
       contrib.contributuion_id,
       contrib.submitter_id,
       (SELECT COUNT(like2.contribution_like_id)
          FROM td_idea_contribution_like like2
         WHERE like2.contribution_id = contrib.contribution_id) AS tot_like
  FROM td_idea idea,
       td_idea_contribution contrib,
       td_idea_contribution_like likes
  WHERE idea.idea_id = contrib.idea_id 
    AND contrib.contribution_id = likes.contribution_id
    AND idea.idea_id = '$id'
    AND idea.status LIKE '%Design%'
  ORDER BY tot_like DESC
```